# Overlay partially hidden with MapKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am currently building an indoor location iPad app, thanks to the IndoorAtlas SDK.

I first tried to build the entire map by myself, but I had quite big accuracy problems, which appeared to be resolved when displayed as an overlay on the maps provided by Apple (MapKit).

But, I now have a problem with my custom floorPlan image Overlay, which seems to be partially hidden by the Apple Map. I already have hidden labels, traffic, points of interest, buildings, and my Map is set to be displayed in standard mode.

The hidden part of my Overlay depends on the altitude of the camera, which makes me believe that the tiles are responsible.

The floorPlan image is added on the map by this function :

```
func indoorLocationManager(manager: IALocationManager, didEnterRegion region: IARegion) {
    print("Floor plan changed to \(region.identifier)")
    ressourceManager.fetchFloorPlanWithId(region.identifier, andCompletion: {
        (floorPlan:IAFloorPlan?, error:NSError?) -> () in
        if error == nil {
            self.floorPlan = floorPlan
            self.fpImage = UIImage(imageLiteral: "Map")
            if self.mapOverlay != nil {
                map.removeOverlay(self.mapOverlay)
            }
            self.mapOverlay = MapOverlay(floorPlan: self.floorPlan!)
            map.addOverlay(self.mapOverlay, level: .AboveRoads)
        } else {
            print("Error fetching floorplan")
        }
    })
}
```

The location is updated as follow :

```
func indoorLocationManager(manager: IALocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
    let loc: CLLocation = (locations.last as! IALocation).location!
    print("Long. \(loc.coordinate.longitude) lat. \(loc.coordinate.latitude)")

    if circle != nil {
        map.removeOverlay(circle)
    }

    circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: loc.coordinate, radius:3)
    map.addOverlay(circle)

    camera = nil
    camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: loc.coordinate, fromEyeCoordinate: loc.coordinate, eyeAltitude: 300)
    camera.heading = loc.course
    map.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
}
```

And my Overlay View is rendered like so :

```
class MapOverlayView : MKOverlayRenderer {

    let floorPlan: IAFloorPlan!
    let image: UIImage!

    init(overlay: MKOverlay, overlayImage: UIImage, floorPlan: IAFloorPlan) {
        self.image = overlayImage
        self.floorPlan = floorPlan
        super.init(overlay: overlay)
    }

    override func drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext ctx: CGContextRef) {
        let theMapRect: MKMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect
        let theRect: CGRect = self.rectForMapRect(theMapRect)
        // Rotate around top left corner
        CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, degreesToRadians(self.floorPlan.bearing))
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        image.drawInRect(theRect, blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }

    func degreesToRadians(x: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(M_PI * x / 180.0)
    }

}
```

The Apple Map is added at initialization, and the Overlay is added later, but I really don't see any reason why it could be a problem ..

One solution could be to just completely hide the Apple Map, but I don't manage to do that without hiding its overlays.

Could the problem come from the loading of the map ? or is it a graphical issue ?

[Here is a screen of the iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxoZs.png)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did u get any solution for it?

Comment: @chandvoid I'm sorry for the delay, I did not see your comment.
It appeared that the problem was similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863781/custom-mkoverlayview-unmodified-mkpolygonview-is-clipped-at-certain-zoom-levels

The coordinates provided by Indoor Atlas were somehow different from the one expected by MapKit. Unfortunately I don't have the code with me anymore, but the idea is, instead of passing the received data directly to your Overlay, manually swap the coordinates.